# Check number of processes in MPI for power of two

Tags: c, mpi, bitwise-operators

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I just want to know whats the actual meaning of the if statement below.

```
int rank, numprocs;
MPI_Status status;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs );
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank     );

if( numprocs&(numprocs-1) )
{
    if( rank==0 ) printf( "numprocs must be a power of 2.\n" );
    MPI_Finalize();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

I was told that "numprocs&(numprocs-1)" is used to check if the numprocs is the power of 2, but how does it work actually? What is the output of the statement? Is it boolean or int?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` operator is bitwise AND operator.

If `numprocs` is the power of 2, its binary representation will contain exactly one bit whose bit is 1.

For example, if `numprocs = 16`, `numprocs - 1 = 15` and their AND will be zero because borrowing in subtraction happens from LSB to the bit whose value is 1.

```
  10000 (16)
& 01111 (15)
------------
  00000 ( 0)
```

Contrary, if `numprocs` is positive and not the power of 2, its binary representations will contain more than one bit whose bit is 1.

For example, if `numprocs = 20`, `numprocs - 1 = 19` and borrowing in subtraction will stop before reaching the topmost bit, so bit whose value is 1 survives and the result won't be zero.

```
  10100 (20)
& 10011 (19)
------------
  10000 (16)
```

The result is `int`. `if` statement in C will treat zero as false and non-zero as true.